# Resize issue with table centered horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

Simple code

```
<table class="box" border="1px">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      my content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and style

```
.box {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#d9d9d9;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-150px;
    /* half of width */
    margin-top:-150px;
    /* half of height */
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
```

(see **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8J6w/)**)

allow to center table horizontally and vertically. However, when window is resized to be smaller than table, even with scroll-bar shown, I am unable to see top of the content. Why?

Comment: Because of the negative top margin?

Comment: try to use % instead of px, this will give your box a responsive element

Comment: *@onetrickpony*, *@Beep* :: nope, none of those is a fix for this issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a minimum height to your document:

```
html{
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

That way the height of the window will never be smaller than the box.

(`height:100%` is needed so your box gets centered)

---

> ...even with scroll-bar shown,

you see the scrollbars because there's content that overflows, but the height of the `html` does not include that extra space (when the negative margin is applied, it does not take into consideration that extra height)

Comment: Why `position:relative;` for `html` is needed?

Comment: Well your box is absolutely positioned, and it looks like you want it centered in the window. So the window element must be positioned. I thought it was by default, and doing it was unnecessary, but it isn't it seems.

Comment: The lack of a positioned ancestor for your box is probably the reason why you get such behavior

Answer (score -1):

```
.box {
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:#d9d9d9;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-150px;
    /* half of width */
    margin-top:-150px;
    /* half of height */
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}

.top {

    margin-left:2cm;
    margin-right:2cm;
    vertical-align:text-top;
}


html

<table class="box" border="1px">
  <tr>
    <td class="top">my content</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Problem of not seeing the top will persist as long as there is a negative margin.

Answer (score -1):

```
.box {
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:#d9d9d9;
    position:absolute;
    top:25%;
    left:25%;
}
```

Comment: Box has to have fixed size (it will be actually a picture in my case), so this is not a solution for me.

Comment: OneTrickPony's approach will do it.