# How to style html element directly (inline)?

Tags: html, css

I have a css style for `html` element, such as:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

If it is style for `body` or any element within body, I can apply styling directly using `style="..."` parameter of such element.

But how can I apply style to `html` element directly (inline)?

Comment: Bearing in mind that you should avoid inline styling, the same method should work on the `<html>` tag. Is it not working for you when you inline it?

Comment: _Directly_ you mean __inline__ (as the _style_ attribute)?

Comment: Works [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8tTAy/)

Comment: @j08691 - Why should I **avoid** inline styling? What is wrong with that?

Comment: For a few reasons see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721997/inline-styles-vs-styles-in-css. Or just Google "avoid inline CSS".

Comment: @j08691 - I use inline styling for very simple page with no issue

Comment: I'm not saying it won't work. It's just something to avoid. Best practice type stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do it the same as you described in the `body` example:

```
<html style="position: relative; height: 100%; min-height: 300px;">
```

---

**But beware that inline styles are bad practice**. Don't use them unless you have a really serious reason. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721997/inline-styles-vs-styles-in-css) mentioned in the comments of this very question.

Comment: Also, wouldn't the "position:relative" be irrelevant? The `<html>` block is at the top level of the document; everything contained inside it /by default/ is relative to that space.

Comment: @mori57 - To my surprise, it is not irrelevant - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521309/resize-issue-with-table-centered-horizontally-and-vertically

Comment: I feel saying "inline styles are bad" is rather misleading. Although they are harder to maintain, they don't affect performance or cause other `bad` things to happen. It is more a matter of "practice" and "personal preference".  Maybe a better way to phrase it is to say "inline styles are considered bad practice". Just a thought.

Comment: @ΩmegaΔ ... Interesting, I would have thought that the base element was indeed the relative container for all others in an HTML doc. Ah well, learn something new every day, right? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

That's not proper but you can do it with

```
<html style="background-color:red;">
```